# How do I properly connect my Nest-Js/Angular docker-compose images to my host computer?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So, It's been a few weeks now, and after some successful attempts, I have been getting the "This connection was reset" whenever I try and connect to my docker container. 
Here's my Docker-compose

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:10-alpine'
    container_name: 'postgres'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=4321
      - POSTGRES_DB=twr
    volumes:
      - twrdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend: 
    build: ./backendtwr
    volumes:
      - ./backendtwr:/app
    ports: 
      - 4000:8080
    links: 
       - db
  frontend:
    build: ./frontendtwr
    volumes: 
      - ./frontendtwr:/app
    ports:
      - 4001:4200
    links:
      - backend
```

And my Frontend Docker File

```
#base image
FROM node:10.16.0
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install d3
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200
# start app
CMD ng serve
```

I've added npm install d3 because it refuses to install d3 from my package.json. Incidentally around the time I added that line, I have been unable to view my app from my host-computer; with the error

```
This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

from my Chrome

For additional info: here's the dockerfile for my backend, which runs on my browser with no problem whatsoever.

```
#base image
FROM node:8.12.0
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
# start app
CMD npm run start:dev
```

Comment: I look for localhost:4001 on the browser

Comment: Your `volumes:` declarations are hiding everything your Dockerfiles do; if you're finding missing packages when you run your image this could be a cause.  I'd delete both `volumes:` blocks (and also the useless `links:`).

Comment: Is the container actually starting up?  Is it listening on 0.0.0.0:4200 (not the container's private localhost interface)?  Any other interesting error messages?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I put the Volume blocks so that I could edit them live (trying to set up a dev-envt (perhaps I'm doing it wrong?. 
I did remove the link-blocks, though.. You're right, they were useless. 
I don't know what you mean by 
"Is it listening on 0.0.0.0:4200 (not the container's private localhost interface)? 0.0.0.0:4200 on my browser just says 0.0.0.0 refuses to connect.
But there's no other interesting error message
Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: @DavidMaze what's weird, is that the container for the nodejs app (which is almost identical to the angular one) pops up on my browser at localhost:4000

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:10-alpine'
    container_name: 'postgresnew'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=4321
      - POSTGRES_DB=twr
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  frontend:
    build: ./frontendtwr
    ports:
      - 4001:4200
    volumes: 
      - ./frontendtwr:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
  backend: 
    build: ./backendtwr
    ports: 
      - 4000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./backendtwr:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    env_file:
      - .env
volumes: 
  pgdata:
```

This fixed it...
as @DavidMaze said, I was using the volume blocks wrong.